# Scalaj how to pass authentication credentials

Tags: scala, rest, get

here is my GET request and how do you pass authentication credentials

```
 import scalaj.http_
 val result = Http("http://myserver03.abc.com:8983/sol/Collection/select?").param("q", "smith").asString
```

Answer (score 1):

nevermind figured out

```
 val result = Http("http://myserver03.abc.com:8983/sol/Collection/select?").param("q", "smith").auth("user", "password").asString
```

would be helpfull to know how to pass encrypted Base64 credentials

Answer (score 1):

To pass encrypted Base64 credentials, you can use below code.

```
val result = Http("http://myserver03.abc.com:8983/sol/Collection/select?").param("q", "smith").header("Authorization", "Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==").asString
```

user:password
Base64 encode value: dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==