# Build Jenkins pipeline using HttpRequest

Tags: scala, http, jenkins, akka

I try to execute a jenkins pipeline from a Scala app, but the authentication is required. So, I think before this request, I need to call the auth endpoint and get a token, then assign it on the headers.

```
val userToken = "user_token_generated_in_jenkins"
val pipelineToken = "pipeline_token"
val pipelineName = "HttpRequestTest"

// test1
val baseUrl = s"http://jenkins_address/view/Development/job/$pipelineName/build?token=$pipelineToken"
val response = Http(baseUrl).headers("token" -> "tried_a_valid_token_auth").asString

// test2
val url = s"http://auto:$userToken@jenkins_address/job/$pipelineName/build?token=$pipelineToken"
val response2 = Http(url).asString
```

If I can be sure that first test is wrong, why for test2, where I use the user token (generated in Users manager), it asks me to use extra token (generated by authentication)? Is a double verification and useless in my opinion.

*As an emergency solution, I can execute the pipeline with `curl` using `sys.process`. But I prefer to solve it using Http library because I want to use generated token and not a specific username in my project code.*

```
// test3
import sys.process._
val data = List("curl", "-u", "username:password", baseUrl).!!
```

How can I execute an HttpRequest using Jenkins User Token?

Thanks

Comment: I think you are mixing 2 different questions. Can you make the request using `"username:password"` with http? Can you use the jenkins token using curl? Try to isolate your problem.

Comment: I tought I can use Jenkins Token as http header, but not. I want to do an HttpRequest with or without token or credentials, but if I generated a token in Jenkins for a specified user, I expected that I can use it in an header of an http request.

Comment: So do you want to edit your question? Or do you even have a question here? Or you figured it out?

Comment: ya, updated. you can just ignore sys.process solution. I need just a httprequest using user token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `Http(..)` is from Akk-HTTP, the solution could be derived from [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0/common/http-model.html):

```
val authorization = headers.Authorization(BasicHttpCredentials("username", "password"))
HttpRequest(
  PUT,
  uri = "/user",
  entity = HttpEntity(`text/plain` withCharset `UTF-8`, userData),
  headers = List(authorization),
  protocol = `HTTP/1.0`)
```

In case of [scalaj-http](https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-http) it could be derived from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52412066/scalaj-how-to-pass-authentication-credentials)
With applying to your existing code, it should be like this:

```
Http(baseUrl).auth("username", "password").asString
```

By the way

> I want to use generated token and not a specific username in my
> project code

It is not a problem. You can construct your process' auth string dynamically. You are able to get the credentials from somewhere in the "native" `Http` solution, right? So you can construct your `sys.process` with the same getted-from-somewhere credentials by concatinating strings or string interpolation:

```
// test3
import sys.process._
val (username, password) = gettingFromSomewhereCreadentials()
val data = List("curl", "-u", s"$username:$password", baseUrl).!!
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. For second example, I can not resolve overloaded method Http, when I try to give it the url as parameter, Http(url). And if I use first approach, seems like the request is never executed

Comment: "For second example, I can not resolve overloaded method Http, when I try to give it the url as parameter, Http(url)" - it is a copy of your "test 2" code block. Your code block is not working too? | In the first approach I guess u can execute it somewhere later. See the documentation how to run such constructed request.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to specify, I use Http() from scalaj in this example, not from akka-http. I tried both anyway

Comment: edited it to scalaj version. haven't tested. hope it helps

Comment: thanks, it works. I need to be more careful in the future